# AutoCompleteBox with TextChanged event not selecting properly

Tags: silverlight, xaml, silverlight-5.0

Hi I'm using an **AutoCompleteBox** like this

```
<!-- XAML Code -->
<sdk:AutoCompleteBox Grid.Row="2"
         FilterMode="None"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}"
         SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedCustomer, Mode=TwoWay}"
         Text="{Binding CustomerSearchString, Mode=TwoWay}"
         ValueMemberBinding="{Binding Path=FullName}"
         ValueMemberPath="FullName"
         TextChanged="{ext:Invoke MethodName=Search, Source={Binding}}"/>
```

C# part:

```
// Search Method in the viewmodel
public void Search()
{
    var customerOperation = _context.Load(_context.GetCustomerByNameQuery(CustomerSearchString));
    customerOperation.Completed += (s, e) => Customers = new List<Customer>(customerOperation.Entities);
}
```

In my app to quick-search for customers for an fast and uncomplicated method to search. I get it to display everything correctly in the dropdown, and when I select with the mouse it works perfectly.

But when I press *ArrowDown*, you see the text come up for a split-second but then it reverts and puts the cursor back in the textbox instead of selecting the first entry down. I tried using the TextInput event, but that one won't fire.

How can I avoid this behaviour?

**SOLUTION:**

The problem was, that the TextChanged event got fired when the user selected an entry, creating some sort of race condition like behaviour where the Text got reset. *The solution was to use the **KeyUp** event (don't use KeyDown, because the Text property won't be updated yet). This event doesn't get triggered when the user selects something, solving the problem.*

**Final code (ViewModel unchanged):**

```
<!-- XAML Code -->
<sdk:AutoCompleteBox Grid.Row="2"
         FilterMode="None"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}"
         SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedCustomer, Mode=TwoWay}"
         Text="{Binding CustomerSearchString, Mode=TwoWay}"
         ValueMemberBinding="{Binding Path=FullName}"
         ValueMemberPath="FullName"
         KeyUp="{ext:Invoke MethodName=Search, Source={Binding}}"/>
```

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a handler like this in code:

```
KeyEventHandler eventHandler = MyAutoCompleteBox_KeyDown;
MyAutoCompleteBox.AddHandler(KeyDownEvent, eventHandler, true);
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks, that was almost the solution, BUT: a) I use XAML-Markup because I don't want code and I used KeyUp, because on KeyDown the Text property wasn't updated yet. Thanks and congrats to 50 points :D

Answer (score 0):

I'm not understanding why you are using a TextChanged event...? What is that for? If you take that out, does it work? I use an autocomplete box in my project and I don't need a search method... all I do is just supply a list of objects to the autocompletebox and the it searches that list when the user types. I can select either by mouse or by up/down arrows. The only thing that I can think of is that each time you try to use the up/down arrow the text changes and fires off the search function and closes the selection option drop down...

Comment: I use it to search because the entire collection can't be digested by RIA Services, and it also would be too much data (over 10'000 datasets).